# differ load of control on page load

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have updatepanel and panel on web page. I want to load panel on page load but load updatepanel on page loadcomplete. problem is how can I differ load of updatepanel on page load?

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to load your UpdatePanel after the page loads (ie: after the page has been fully rendered by the browser,) then you can put a Timer control on the page and set the UpdatePanel to be triggered by the timer.  In the Timer_Tick event, stop your timer and do whatever you need to do in the UpdatePanel.